# shell-resync-dirs hangs

Tags: debugging, shell-mode

When I run `shell-resync-dirs` <sup>1</sup>, the function hangs, until I press `C-g`, at which this point, what looks suspiciously like the output of my shell's `dirs -l` command <sup>2</sup> gets inserted into my buffer at point, and my shell prints a newline and a new prompt.  (Point remains unchanged throughout all this.)  As far as I can tell, the `shell-resync-dirs` never gets to do what it is supposed to do, since `shell-dirstack` remains unchanged (and as out-of-sync as it was when I invoked the function).

I would like to find out why `shell-resync-dirs` hangs when I invoke it.

In particular, I would like to trace the execution of `shell-resync-dirs`.

Naively, I tried using `trace-function`, but this did not have the desired effect.  All I get from this is that Emacs will notify me when `shell-resync-dirs` starts execution and when it terminates, which tells me nothing that I don't already know.

Is there a simple way to trace the evaluation of the various expressions *within* the definition of `shell-resync-dirs`?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For this post, please assume that the current buffer is an inferior shell started with `M-x shell`.  Also, my shell is `/bin/zsh`.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> For what it's worth, `"dirs -l"` is the value I have assigned to the variable `shell-dirstack-query`.</sup>

Comment: That happens to me occasionally as well, but I've never figured out the root cause. Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and discovered that I had `comint-process-echoes` set to `t` in `comint-mode-hook`,  I think as part of some experiment with using `zsh` instead of `bash`. Setting it back to the default of `nil` fixed the `M-x dirs` hanging issue for me.